# Is there any way to easily remove hidden inputs from an html form?

Tags: html, forms, input

We have an assessment engine in which the questions contain form inputs (input, select, etc). In order to display the answer, we replicated the question exactly and display the correct answer. By default the answer is a hidden copy of the question, and we just intended to display it and set the value to the correct answer. There is no security issue because the quiz does not contain the information as to the correct answer until the user clicks to populate, and the server will not give the information until after a release day/time.

However, just having the inputs mirrored means that it looks like the quiz has double the number of inputs. Is there any way to flag inputs in a form to be ignored (ie, NOT SENT to the server?)

Otherwise, the easy way to do this seems to be to write two pages, one with only questions, and one with questions and answers.

```
<form method="post" action="grade">
What is 2+2?
<input id="q1_1">
<div class="answer">
  <input id="a_1_1">
</div>
</form>
```

The CSS for answer contains display: none so at first, the answers are not displayed, and they can be dynamically made viewable by JavaScript.

Comment: removing name attribute of input elements will prevent its value being sent to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled#Attribute_interactions) attribute on the input will omit it from the form post.

> …disabled controls can not receive focus and are not submitted with the form…